# Is there a way to take a list of strings and create a JSON file, where both the key and value are list items?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am creating a python script that can read scanned, and tabular .pdfs and extract some important data and insert it into a JSON to later be implemented into a SQL database (I will also be developing the DB as a project for learning MongoDB).

Basically, my issue is I have never worked with any JSON files before but that was the format I was recommended to output to. The scraping script works, the pre-processing could be a lot cleaner, but for now it works. The issue I run into is the keys, and values are in the same list, and some of the values because they had a decimal point are two different list items. Not really sure where to even start.

I don't really know where to start, I suppose since I know what the indexes of the list are I can easily assign keys and values, but then it may not be applicable to any .pdf, that is the script cannot be coded explicitly.

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf2
import textract

with "TestSpec.pdf" as filename:
    pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')
    pdfReader = pdf2.pdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    num_pages = pdfReader.numpages
    count = 0
    text = ""

    while count < num_pages:
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
        count += 1
        text += pageObj.extractText()

    if text != "":
        text = text
    else:
        text = textract.process(filename, method="tesseract", language="eng")

def cleanText(x):
    '''
    This function takes the byte data extracted from scanned PDFs, and cleans it of all
    unnessary data.
    Requires re
    '''
    stringedText = str(x)
    cleanText = stringedText.replace('\n','')
    splitText = re.split(r'\W+', cleanText)
    caseingText = [word.lower() for word in splitText]
    cleanOne = [word for word in caseingText if word != 'n']
    dexStop = cleanOne.index("od260")
    dexStart = cleanOne.index("sheet")
    clean = cleanOne[dexStart + 1:dexStop]
    return clean

cleanText = cleanText(text)
```

This is the current output

```
['n21', 'feb', '2019', 'nsequence', 'lacz', 'rp', 'n5', 'gat', 'ctc', 'tac', 'cat', 'ggc', 'gca', 'cat', 'ttc', 'ccc', 'gaa', 'aag', 'tgc', '3', 'norder', 'no', '15775199', 'nref', 'no', '207335463', 'n25', 'nmole', 'dna', 'oligo', '36', 'bases', 'nproperties', 'amount', 'of', 'oligo', 'shipped', 'to', 'ntm', '50mm', 'nacl', '66', '8', 'xc2', 'xb0c', '11', '0', '32', '6', 'david', 'cook', 'ngc', 'content', '52', '8', 'd260', 'mmoles', 'kansas', 'state', 'university', 'biotechno', 'nmolecular', 'weight', '10', '965', '1', 'nnmoles']
```

and we want the output as a JSON setup like

```
{"Date | 21feb2019", "Sequence ID: | lacz-rp", "Sequence 5'-3' | gat..."}
```

and so on. Just not sure how to do that.

here is a screenshot of the data from my sample pdf [image: my sample pdf]

So, i have figured out some of this. I am still having issues with grabbing the last 3rd of the data i need without explicitly programming it in. but here is what i have so far. Once i have everything working then  i will worry about optimizing it and condensing.

```
# for PDF reading
import PyPDF2 as pdf2
import textract
# for data preprocessing
import re
from dateutil.parser import parse
# For generating the JSON file array
import json
# This finds and opens the pdf file, reads the data, and extracts the data.
filename = "*.pdf"
pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')
pdfReader = pdf2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
text = ""
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
text += pageObj.extractText()

# checks if extracted data is in string form or picture, if picture textract reads data.
# it then closes the pdf file
if text != "":
    text = text
else:
    text = textract.process(filename, method="tesseract", language="eng")
pdfFileObj.close()

# Converts text to string from byte data for preprocessing
stringedText = str(text)
# Removed escaped lines and replaced them with actual new lines.
formattedText = stringedText.replace('\\n', '\n').lower()
# Slices the long string into a workable piece (only contains useful data)
slice1 = formattedText[(formattedText.index("sheet") + 10): (formattedText.index("secondary") - 2)]
clean = re.sub('\n', " ", slice1)
clean2 = re.sub(' +', ' ', clean)

# Creating the PrimerData dictionary
with open("PrimerData.json",'w') as file:
    primerDataSlice = clean[clean.index("molecular"): -1]
    primerData = re.split(": |\n", primerDataSlice)
    primerKeys = primerData[0::2]
    primerValues = primerData[1::2]
    primerDict = {"Primer Data": dict(zip(primerKeys,primerValues))}
    # Generatring the JSON array "Primer Data"
    primerJSON = json.dumps(primerDict, ensure_ascii=False)
    file.write(primerJSON)

# Grabbing the date (this has just the date, so json will have to add date.)
date = re.findall('(\d{2}[\/\- ](\d{2}|january|jan|february|feb|march|mar|april|apr|may|may|june|jun|july|jul|august|aug|september|sep|october|oct|november|nov|december|dec)[\/\- ]\d{2,4})', clean2)
```

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Some of it. I am having trouble grabbing the stuff between the date and Properties without explicitly programming it. the Cleaning part is what was causing most of the issues. I am going to edit the post now to add what i have gotten so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did figure this out, the problem was really just that because of the way my pre-processing was pulling all the data into a single list wasn't really that great of an idea considering that the `keys` for the dictionary never changed.

Here is the semi-finished result for making the Dictionary and JSON file.

```py
# Collect the sequence name
name = clean2[clean2.index("Sequence") + 11: clean2.index("Sequence") + 19]
# Collecting Shipment info
ordered = input("Who placed this order? ")
received = input("Who is receiving this order? ")
dateOrder = re.findall(
    r"(\d{2}[/\- ](\d{2}|January|Jan|February|Feb|March|Mar|April|Apr|May|June|Jun|July|Jul|August|Aug|September|Sep|October|Oct|November|Nov|December|Dec)[/\- ]\d{2,4})",
    clean2)
dateReceived = date.today()
refNo = clean2[clean2.index("ref.No. ") + 8: clean2.index("ref.No.") + 17]
orderNo = clean2[clean2.index("Order No.") +
                 10: clean2.index("Order No.") + 18]
# Finding and grabbing the sequence data. Storing it and then finding the
# GC content and melting temp or TM
bases = int(clean2[clean2.index("bases") - 3:clean2.index("bases") - 1])
seqList = [line for line in clean2 if re.match(r'^[AGCT]+$', line)]
sequence = "".join(i for i in seqList[:bases])


def gc_content(x):
    count = 0
    for i in x:
        if i == 'G' or i == 'C':
            count += 1
        else:
            count = count
    return round((count / bases) * 100, 1)


gc = gc_content(sequence)
tm = mt.Tm_GC(sequence, Na=50)
moleWeight = round(mw(Seq(sequence, generic_dna)), 2)
dilWeight = float(clean2[clean2.index("ug/OD260:") +
                         10: clean2.index("ug/OD260:") + 14])
dilution = dilWeight * 10
primerDict = {"Primer Data": {
    "Sequence": sequence,
    "Bases": bases,
    "TM (50mM NaCl)": tm,
    "% GC content": gc,
    "Molecular weight": moleWeight,
    "ug/0D260": dilWeight,
    "Dilution volume (uL)": dilution
},
    "Shipment Info": {
        "Ref. No.": refNo,
        "Order No.": orderNo,
        "Ordered by": ordered,
        "Date of Order": dateOrder,
        "Received By": received,
        "Date Received": str(dateReceived.strftime("%d-%b-%Y"))
    }}
# Generating the JSON array "Primer Data"
with open("".join(name) + ".json", 'w') as file:
    primerJSON = json.dumps(primerDict, ensure_ascii=False)
    file.write(primerJSON)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without input data it is difficult to give you working code. A minimal working example with input would help. As for JSON handling, python dictionaries can dump to json easily. See examples here.
https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/json/

Get a json string from a dictionary and write to a file. Figure out how to parse the text into a dictionary.

```
import json
d = {"Date" : "21feb2019", "Sequence ID" : "lacz-rp", "Sequence 5'-3'" : "gat"}
json_data = json.dumps(d)
print(json_data)
# Write that data to a file
```

Comment: I suppose i could post a picture of the scanned PDF, the output i posted is the data from the sample pdf. However, if it is important i can post a screenshot of it